# Am able to log in via ssh but not able to use scp in ubuntu 14.04 reinstall

Tags: ssh, scp

I am able to log in via ssh but not able to use scp in ubuntu 14.04 after reinstall.  I keep getting the message

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
2e:6a:e2:65:39:1f:ab:e4:21:34:48:6d:2b:7a:25:7b.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/dynamix/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /home/dynamix/.ssh/known_hosts:21
RSA host key for 10.21.50.126 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

However if I log in to that machine and copy back files to my system it works. Please help.
Already installed ssh from package manager

(Recently reinstalled OS)

Comment: I removed the contents of the known_hosts file in the systems from where I need to do scp. Then everything is fine. However for server machines where I do not have permission to do so, I am unable to do  scp. Any suggestions?

Comment: the known_host file should be on the client side not the server and should be writable for the user as it's a user file.

Comment: Okay. Rectified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well what it is saying is that the RSA Fingerprint has changed which will happen if you reinstall the OS on the remote system or you reassign an IP or DNS record to a new system. As long as you are sure you have the right system, you can remove the entry for that host on line 21 of the /home/dynamix/.ssh/known_hosts file. Since 10.21.50.126 is a private network, you are probably pretty safe. (Though that does not count for free wifi at your local cafe which will probably also use Private IPs and could have a hacker on the network)

As to why scp gives you this error and not ssh, I am not sure. Are you logging in as the same user?

Answer (score 1):

Open this file with vim and delete line 21 number entry it solves your problem /home/dynamix/.ssh/known_hosts.